# Unable to generalise data operations in Haskell, ambiguous return type

Tags: haskell, newtype, union-types

I'm trying to generalise some code I have around generating a report around various views of a range of dates, for example the view could be like this:

```
      | Signups | Active users 
------|---------|--------------
 2018 | 155     | 3241         
 2017 | 139     | 3083         
 2016 | 125     | 2543
```

Or it could be switched to a month view like this:

```
         | Signups | Active users 
---------|---------|--------------
 08/2018 | 15      | 324            
 07/2018 | 13      | 308          
 06/2018 | 12      | 254
```

You get the idea... So I thought it would make sense to generalise each 'mode' you can set this data to render in, it supports days / weeks / months / quarters / years.

```
data DateField
  = DateFieldDay CalendarDay
  | DateFieldWeek CalendarWeek
  | DateFieldMonth CalendarMonth
  | DateFieldQuarter CalendarQuarter
  | DateFieldYear CalendarYear

instance Calendar DateField where
  fromDay = DateFieldDay . fromDay
  fallsWithin = \case
    DateFieldDay calendar -> fallsWithin calendar
    DateFieldWeek calendar -> fallsWithin calendar
    DateFieldMonth calendar -> fallsWithin calendar
    DateFieldQuarter calendar -> fallsWithin calendar
    DateFieldYear calendar -> fallsWithin calendar

instance ToJSON DateField where
  toJSON = \case
    DateFieldDay calendar -> toJSON calendar
    DateFieldWeek calendar -> toJSON calendar
    DateFieldMonth calendar -> toJSON calendar
    DateFieldQuarter calendar -> toJSON calendar
    DateFieldYear calendar -> toJSON calendar

class Calendar c where
  fromDay :: Day -> c
  fallsWithin :: c -> Day -> Bool

newtype CalendarDay = CalendarDay Day   

instance Calendar CalendarDay where
  fromDay = CalendarDay
  fallsWithin (Calendar dayField) day = day == dayField 

instance ToJSON CalendarDay where
  toJSON (CalendarDay day) = toJSON day

-- instances for CalendarWeek, CalendarMonth etc etc
```

So my issue arises with the fact that instances from my sum type `DateField` have to implement the same function twice `extractCalendar`... But I am unable to generalise this, and have to effectively leave it defined twice, I cannot define something like this:

```
extractCalendar :: (Calendar c, ToJSON c) => DateField -> c
extractCalendar = \case
  DateFieldDay calendar -> calendar
  DateFieldWeek calendar -> calendar
  DateFieldMonth calendar -> calendar
  DateFieldQuarter calendar -> calendar
  DateFieldYear calendar -> calendar
```

Because the inner types are all `newtypes` and the type signature for `extractCalendar` is somewhat non-sensical.

I'm not sure if this is actually making the code worse by trying to generalise like this, and can't really work out where to take the code from here.

The other portion of this code I would like to share is as follows:

```
generateRange :: MonadIO m => DateView -> m [DateField]
generateRange view = rangeToFields . takeWhile includeDate <$> dateStream
  where
    rangeToFields dates =
      case view of
        DateViewDay -> DateFieldDay <$> foldr calendarDays [] dates
        DateViewWeek -> DateFieldWeek <$> foldr calendarWeeks [] dates
        DateViewMonth -> DateFieldMonth <$> foldr calendarMonths [] dates
        DateViewQuarter -> DateFieldQuarter <$> foldr calendarQuarters [] dates
        DateViewYear -> DateFieldYear <$> foldr calendarYears [] dates

    calendarDays day acc =
      if True
         then fromDay day : acc
         else acc

    calendarWeeks day acc =
      if True
         then fromDay day : acc
         else acc

    calendarMonths day acc =
      if dayDate day == 1
         then fromDay day : acc
         else acc

    calendarQuarters day acc =
      if dayDate day == 1 && (dayMonth day `mod` 3 == 0)
         then fromDay day : acc
         else acc

    calendarYears day acc =
      if dayDate day == 1 && dayMonth day == 1
         then fromDay day : acc
         else acc

    includeDate day =
      dayYear day >= 2014
```

It takes a stream of days, from today back into the past one day after the next, and then folds over these generating the relevant `DateField` depending on which `DateView` is provided.

I feel like I am misusing the `typeclass` construct here... but I am unsure how to achieve the generalisation I want in Haskell with any other structure...

Answer (score 1):

The instances of `Calendar` seem to be essentially various *time intervals*. Then why don't you make the methods

```
  asInterval :: c -> (UTCTime, UTCTime)
  -- e.g. asInterval (Day 2018-8-15) ≡ (2018-8-15_0:0:0, 2018-8-16_0:0:0)
  containingInterval :: (UTCTime, UTCTime) -> Maybe c
  -- e.g. containingInterval (2018-8-5_0:0:0, 2018-8-22_0:0:0) :: Maybe Month
  --            ≡ Just (Month 2018-8)
  --      containingInterval (2018-8-5_0:0:0, 2018-8-22_0:0:0) :: Maybe Week
  --            ≡ Nothing
```

That would allow

```
containing :: (Calendar c, Calendar c') => c -> Maybe c'
containing = containingInterval . asInterval
```

and that could be used

```
extractCalendar :: (Calendar c, ToJSON c) => DateField -> Maybe c
extractCalendar = \case
  DateFieldDay calendar -> containing calendar
  DateFieldWeek calendar -> containing calendar
  DateFieldMonth calendar -> containing calendar
  DateFieldQuarter calendar -> containing calendar
  DateFieldYear calendar -> containing calendar
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `instance ToJSON DateField` is problematic because it doesn't distinguish between types of DateField. You should add a type tag to the JSON, like this:

```
instance ToJSON DateField where
  toJSON (DateFieldDay calendar) = object [
       "type" .= "DateFieldDay",
       "calendar" .= calendar ]
  -- etc
```

Then in the FromJSON instance you can use a case statement to discriminate on the `"type"` field.